# Is $\frac{z-\alpha}{1-\overline{\alpha}z}$ some special function in complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis

Many homework problems seem to use the following function (or something very close to it):

$$F_\alpha(z)=\frac{z-\alpha}{1-\overline{\alpha}z}$$

Does it serve some special purposes in complex analysis?

It does revolve around the unit circle.

Comment: it is a special case of a moebius transform

Answer (score 3):

This is "the" conformal map from $\mathbb{D}$ to itself that sends $a$ with $0$, and is unique up to rotation. Applications include things such as the [Schwarz-Pick theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz.E2.80.93Pick_theorem).

Comment: But $F_\alpha(0) = -\alpha$...?

Comment: @Unit Sorry, had it worded wrong.